# poco library linking issue in Solaris platform

Tags: c++

I have build the poco library in solaris. My system configuration is SunOS solaris2 5.10 Generic_144488-07 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T1000. When I tried to run the sample which was provided along with the sample I am able to build and run the sample application. But when I wrote a seperate program and tried to link with poco library, I am getting the following error

**ld: fatal: file /74bkp/ramesh/poco-1.4.7p1/lib/SunOS/sun4v/libPocoXML.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ld: fatal: file /74bkp/ramesh/poco-1.4.7p1/lib/SunOS/sun4v/libPocoFoundation.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32**

I use the following command to compile the source

**g++ -I/74bkp/ramesh/poco-1.4.7p1/XML/include -I/74bkp/ramesh/poco-1.4.7p1/Foundation/include -L/74bkp/ramesh/poco-1.4.7p1/lib/SunOS/sun4v DOMParser.cpp -lPocoXML -lPocoFoundation -m64**

Can some one please give a clue. I could not move further.

regards,
Sam Mouli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have built 32-bit binaries of Poco, therefore you cannot link them to 64-bit binaries.

Remove the `-m64` option from the compiler call and optionally add `-m32`, then it should work. Alternatively, build 64-bit binaries of Poco and link to them.